# create xsd from db model

Tags: xml, c#-3.0, xsd

hi quick question? what is the easiest way to generate an xsd schema file from a database model/design? is it possible to create it from the .edmx file in Entity framework somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) with your assembly containing the edmx as a parameter. You might want to specify type:/ switch to narrow the output to just the necessary classes.